# Using C# Program to Interpret Keystrokes

Tags: c++, keyboard

I am in the process of developing an Arduino application that can read keystrokes from a PS/2 keyboard. I was wondering if it would be possible to upload a C# program onto the Arduino to interpret the keystrokes from the keyboard and write an Arduino program to perform operations based on the keystrokes.

Comment: No, the Arduino doesn't run C#

Comment: Is there a specific feature of C# you need help working around in C++?

Comment: C# is just my go to language. I haven't dabbled in C++ at all, but I guess this would be a good time to pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually, surprisingly, yes! C# requires `.NET CLR` for execution, I had assumed that `.NET` exists only in microsoft desktop land, but it has in fact been ported to [microcontrollers and released open source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj610646.aspx) as `.NET micro`, it can even run baremetal with no OS.

However this is not possible on an 8 bit regular arduino, it requires one of the larger 32 bit models. There is a prebuilt clone that has the `.NET micro CLR` framework ported to it on an STM32F4 cpu called the [netduino](http://www.netduino.com/)

Unfortunately the footprint for .Net Micro is too large to run on a regular 8bit arduino and probably hasn't been built for 8bit systems. It is possible with the arduino Due (in theory) and on other micrcontroller platforms that support `.NET micro` to run C# code outside of the windows platform.

Comment: This is interesting... will this work on something like Arduino Due or another 32 bit Arduino board?

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin it requires reasonable resources (256K Flash + 64K ram), but otherwise the devil will be in configuring/building it for the Arduino Due platform, I'm not sure how easy Microsoft makes it on you, I couldn't find anyone working on it after a cursory search for .net micro on arduino due

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer doesn't get voted down just because it addresses the generic need (do something upon input from a PS/2 keyboard), rather than the (too) specific question that was asked (use c# on Arduino), but here it comes ...

If you use a PS/2 to USB adapter for the keyboard, you can select a much easier solution, based, for example, on raspberry PI (or anything that runs linux and has a USB master port) and use any simple scripting language - even shell. The overall cost would not be much higher and the ease of implementation would be definitely more likely to succeed. And in a short time.